# Xamarin Android - OnServicesDiscovered never called after calling bluetoothGatt.DiscoverServices() for a BLE device

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to discover services for a BLE device in Xamarin Android app.

I successfully discovered the BLE device. But when I call the bluetoothGatt.DiscoverServices() method, OnServicesDiscovered() event handler of BluetoothGattCallback is never gets called.

My development environment is - Visual studio 2015, C#, Xamarin Forms, Android mobile (Lollipop).

Here are the logs -

```
Android: mGatt null and connectGatt called
12-01 11:24:17.811 I/mono-stdout(19643): Android: mGatt null and connectGatt called
12-01 11:24:17.815 D/BluetoothDevice(19643): mAddress: 00:A0:50:18:1F:0A
12-01 11:24:17.816 D/BluetoothGatt(19643): connect() - device: 00:A0:50:18:1F:0A, auto: false
12-01 11:24:17.816 D/BluetoothGatt(19643): registerApp()
12-01 11:24:17.816 D/BluetoothGatt(19643): registerApp() - UUID=e290958f-d7dc-4788-9762-99feac2801bf
12-01 11:24:17.820 D/BluetoothGatt(19643): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=1
12-01 11:24:17.820 D/BluetoothDevice(19643): mAddress: 00:A0:50:18:1F:0A
12-01 11:24:18.119 D/BluetoothGatt(19643): onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=1 device=00:A0:50:18:1F:0A
12-01 11:24:18.119 D/BluetoothDevice(19643): mAddress: 00:A0:50:18:1F:0A
Thread started:  #8
Android: OnConnectionStateChange: -Connected
12-01 11:24:18.158 I/mono-stdout(19643): Android: OnConnectionStateChange: -Connected
XM> DeviceConnected
12-01 11:24:18.168 I/mono-stdout(19643): XM> DeviceConnected
[0:] XM> DeviceConnected
XM> Discover Services
12-01 11:24:18.175 I/mono-stdout(19643): XM> Discover Services
[0:] XM> Discover Services
12-01 11:24:18.179 D/BluetoothDevice(19643): mAddress: 00:A0:50:18:1F:0A
12-01 11:24:18.179 D/BluetoothGatt(19643): discoverServices() - device: 00:A0:50:18:1F:0A
12-01 11:24:18.179 D/BluetoothDevice(19643): mAddress: 00:A0:50:18:1F:0A
Android: DiscoverServices - Bool - True
12-01 11:24:18.180 I/mono-stdout(19643): Android: DiscoverServices - Bool - True
12-01 11:24:21.368 D/BluetoothGatt(19643): onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=1 device=00:A0:50:18:1F:0A
12-01 11:24:21.368 D/BluetoothDevice(19643): mAddress: 00:A0:50:18:1F:0A
Thread started:  #9
Android: OnConnectionStateChange: -Disconnected
12-01 11:24:21.387 I/mono-stdout(19643): Android: OnConnectionStateChange: -Disconnected
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #7
The thread 'Unknown' (0x7) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I can give more information if this is not sufficient. I have wasted many hours and still haven't succeed. Please help!!!

Thanks.
Jkm

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this?